# How to split a frame (of beamer) into 2 parts (minipage) side by side?

Tags: beamer, minipage

I would like to split a frame into 2 parts side by side by minipage. But it seems that the following code puts one on top of the other:

```
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\linewidth}
left part
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\linewidth}
right part
\end{minipage}
```

Could anyone tell me how to do that, and if it is correct to set `0.48\linewidth`?

Comment: The fact that you say "frame" and have tagged this "beamer" makes me think that this is part of a presentation.  Since many things are set up slightly differently for presentations than for ordinary articles, a **minimum working example** is really important here.  Please add a *full* example including preamble.

Comment: could you add more context to your question? Like for example you wrote beamer but you never reference it in the details, could you explain how your question relates to beamer please?

Comment: I found your question useful. The {.48\textwidth} determines the width of each column and you can modify it to make one column wider than the other. Probably you already that, but it seemed to me that that was your question, many years ago.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

A `minipage` or a `parbox` or a box in general need a `\noindent` to prevent the indention at the beginning of a paragraph.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\fboxsep=0pt
\noindent\fbox{%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\linewidth}
left part
\end{minipage}}%
\hfill%
\fbox{%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\linewidth}
right part
\end{minipage}
}

\end{document}
```

I am sure that Raphink knows the answer but you don't provide a minimal example to show the problem.

I used the command `\frame` to demonstrate the left and right part.

[image]

**EDIT:** How Andrew Stacey commented here the solution with `beamer`. `beamer` provides additional features / environments like `columns` which is used in the minimal example. For more details have a look at the documentation.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{columns}[T] % align columns
\begin{column}{.48\textwidth}
\color{red}\rule{\linewidth}{4pt}

Left Part
\end{column}%
\hfill%
\begin{column}{.48\textwidth}
\color{blue}\rule{\linewidth}{4pt}

Right Part
\end{column}%
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why does your example require the `{.48\textwidth}` after you the begin column command?

Comment: Random question, is it possible to insert a dividing line between the Left part and Right part?

Comment: How can I make \fbox lines transparent?

Answer (score 14):

You should add a `\hfill` between the two minipages.

Using `0.48\textwidth` is indeed a correct way of splitting the page.

Comment: it still does not work...

Comment: It works for me. Can you post a MWE?

Comment: Note that editing your question to add `\hfill` makes my answer moot while it doesn't help as long as you don't provide a MWE demonstrating the problem.

Comment: That is true...