# Divide the page into 2 parts

Tags: multicol, tabularx

I have text, formulas and an enumeration. I tried to use `multicols`, but it divides the text where it wants. I used `tabular`, but it don't allow to have an enumeration or I don't know how to do it.
In other words, I want to divide some piece of the page into 2 parts as it is shown in the picture:

[image]

I also want to save an enumeration. See also the border and alignment of the second part of the page. How can I do it in LaTeX?

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11541/how-to-include-enumerate-in-tabular describes how to include a numbered list in a `tabular`, does that help?

Comment: have you tried this with slides in latex?

Comment: for slides: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26836/how-to-split-a-frame-of-beamer-into-2-parts-minipage-side-by-side

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use a `minipage` to achieve this along with a `tabular`. This method will not break across the pages though.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item First item \\
        This is the second line in item and this may extend to third if long
  \item second item\ldots
\end{enumerate}
\end{minipage}%
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
\begin{tabular}{|p{\textwidth}}
This is second part \\
$f(x) = 2x + 3y$ This line may go all along the end and wrap afterwards to the next as seen here\\
This is a forced next line by ending the previous line 
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

It seems the other possibility is with `parallel` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{parallel,enumitem}
\begin{document}
\noindent
Here we use \texttt{parallel} package.
\par
\begin{Parallel}[v]{0.48\textwidth}{0.48\textwidth}
\ParallelLText{\noindent
This is the left side.
\begin{enumerate}[itemsep=1ex,leftmargin=1cm,rightmargin=.52\textwidth]
  \item { First item}
  \item{second item}
\end{enumerate}
And you are back in business.\\
This list can break across pages automatically }
\ParallelRText{\noindent
This goes to the right. This may be going long. If you want you can input equations also.\\
$x=y+10$\\
This may be the best choice if you want this kind of thing to span multiple pages. }
\ParallelPar
\end{Parallel}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have corrected the error, but what I can't understand why the border is wrong.

Comment: @user565447: `\enumerate` leaves a vertical space between first item and the paragraph above it (parsep). Hence put `\parsep=-10pt` as `\begin{enumerate}[parsep=-10pt,itemsep=1ex,leftmargin=1cm,rightmargin=.52\textwidth]`.  border will be alright.

Comment: does the answer change much if you want to use slides?

Comment: also why do you need tabular?

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to use `multicols` and then divide the page on where you want. You can use `\columnbreak` to achieve this.

Here is a complete example demonstrating how to achieve this (which is adapted from the complete [overleaf example here](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Multiple_columns#Inserting_vertical_rulers)):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{1pt}
\def\columnseprulecolor{\color{black}}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
Hello, here is some text without a meaning.  This text should show what 
a printed text will look like at this place.

\begin{enumerate}
  \item { First item}
  \item{second item}
\end{enumerate}

If you want to move to the next column of your choice then do so here.

\columnbreak
This will be in a new column, here is some text without a meaning.  This text 
should show what a printed text will look like at this place.

If you read this text, you will get no information.  Really?  Is there 
no information?  Is there...
\end{multicols}


\end{document}
```

**Visualisation of compiled document**

[image]

Note, to achieve the page split the `\def\columnseprulecolor{\color{black}}` was set at the top of the example, here I have used black, but can be set to other colors, such as blue - for more information, see the [Overleaf Color Documentation](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Using_colors_in_LaTeX).

For reference, I used Overleaf to generate this example.