# How to split page into rectangles?

Tags: line, layout, parallel, organisation

I am trying to make some notes for my math class, and I would like to organize them in the following way: I first want to split the page with a vertical line, and have definitions on the left, theorems on the right. Secondly, I would like to split the page by horizontal lines, which split the material along lectures (illustration at the bottom). Using the answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53544/divide-the-page-into-2-parts), I've managed to split the page by a vertical line. However, I can't figure out the horizontal lines. Any help is greatly appreciated!

**Definitions** | **Theorems**

**Lecture 1** ....| **Lecture 1**

Def 1...........| Thm 1

Def 2...........| Thm 2

Def 3...........|

.---------------------------------

**Lecture 2**....| **Lecture 2**

Def 1...........| Thm 1

Def 2...........| Thm 2

.---------------------------------

and so on.

Comment: Which of the two methods did you use? The one based on two `minipage` enviornments or the one using the `parallel` package? Please also add some more information on the desired alignment. Does one "lecture" part span multiple pages or will two of them always fit onto a single page perfectly? Do you always want to vertically align "Def"  and "Thm"? Where should the second theorem start, if the first theorem is short, but the first definition is long?...

Comment: You can use `\hrule` to draw a horizontal line across the textwidth.

Comment: @leandriis Oh sorry I didn't realize I left out so many details. I used the parallel package. A lecture may span multiple pages. Def and Thm do not have to be aligned at all; they can be completely imdependent.

Comment: Paracol uses column -1 for full width entries (line horizontal lines).

Comment: @JohnKormylo Sorry didn't quite understand, are you saying its possible to make the horizontal lines with Paracol?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the paracol documentation refers to column -1 for spanning text, the only way to access it is through one of the optional arguments.  You can improve the top and bottom spacing by adding `\strut`s.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{paracol}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt}
\begin{document}

\begin{paracol}{2}
\switchcolumn[0]
First column top
\switchcolumn[1]
Second column top
\switchcolumn[0]*[\hrule width\textwidth]
First column bottom
\switchcolumn[1]
Second column bottom
\end{paracol}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!