# Beamer Columns environment doesn't work when converting dvi to pdf

Tags: beamer, minipage, columns

I am trying to create two columns in one slide with Beamer. 
I followed this link:
[How to split a frame (of beamer) into 2 parts (minipage) side by side?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26836/how-to-split-a-frame-of-beamer-into-2-parts-minipage-side-by-side)

However, none of the `minipage` or the `columns` environment works. 
For `columns` environment, my dvi file looks fine but when I convert it to pdf, the page becomes a blank page. 
For `minipage`, I would like to remove the border of each `minipage`. However, once I remove the `\fbox`, the two `minipage` have weird alignment.

I basically use the sample code from the link I mentioned. Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
\usepackage{beamerthemesplit,mathtools,pgf,PSTricks}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[page number]
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{.48\textwidth}
\color{red}\rule{\linewidth}{4pt}
Left Part
\end{column}%
\hfill%
\begin{column}{.48\textwidth}
\color{blue}\rule{\linewidth}{4pt}
Right Part
\end{column}%
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\fboxsep=0pt
\noindent
%\fbox{%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\linewidth}
\includegraphics[height=0.5\paperheight]{impact_circles.eps}
\end{minipage}
%}%
\hfill%
%\fbox{%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\linewidth}
\begin{itemize}
\item right part
\item test2
\item test3
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}
%}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The first slide using `columns` environment, and it is looks fine in dvi file, but it doesn't work after converting to pdf.

The second slide using `minipage` enviroment. It works but the two `minipage` do not align with each other.

Anyone knows how to fix this issue? Thank you.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've included the MWE. I could upload my pdf file if needed.

Comment: So your problem is about misalignment of two columns, right? If that's the case, I would just use the `columns` environment with options `t`, `T`, `c`, and `b` to control the vertical alignments. No need to use `minipage`.

Comment: If I use columns environment, the pdf file doesn't display correctly. Basically, the page becomes blank. I need to covert the dvi file to pdf because some of my figures only show in pdf file. Thanks.

Comment: What's your compilation sequence? It might have to do with the fact that the image you want to include has an `.eps` extension. Have you tried with images of other formats, like `.png` or `.pdf`?

Comment: I first thought that the figure was the problem. However, in my MWE, I didn't put any figures in the frame that has `columns` environment. Hence, I ruled out this possibility. I use latex to compile and then 'dvi to pdf'. I use LED and WinEdt.

Comment: Your first slide looks fine when I compile using `pdflatex` (replacing your image with my own).

Comment: It looks fine when I compile with latex and then convert using dvipdf. I had to comment the image inclusion and correct "PSTricks" (should be lowercase to work on case-sensitive file systems). The only odd thing is that navigation elements appear only after conversion to PDF but I assume that's a font issue. [EDIT: @ Kevin C - I wondered about pdflatex, too, but I assume that the full document needs pstricks so that would not be an option.]

Answer (score 1):

This is more of an extended comment.

## Alignment with `minipage`

You can use the `adjustbox` package to control vertical alignment of the image (load it *before* you load `pstricks` though).

### Code

```
% compile with latex + dvipdfmx 
\documentclass[]{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
\usepackage{mwe} % provides image in this example
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{beamerthemesplit,mathtools,pgf,pstricks}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[page number]

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{with \texttt{minipage}}
\noindent
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\linewidth}
  \adjustbox{valign=T}{\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{image.eps}}
\end{minipage}
\hfill%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\linewidth}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item right part
    \item test2
    \item test3
  \end{itemize}
\end{minipage}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

### Output (despite a lot warnings during `dvipdfmx`)

[image]

## Including a `.eps` image in `columns`

It is by chance that I come to discover that the contents in the frame with `columns` got "pushed" down and to the left for some reason during the `latex`+`dvipdfmx` compilation. This is illustrated by issuing `\vspace{-7cm}` in the following:

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
\usepackage{mwe} % provides image in this example
\usepackage{beamerthemesplit,mathtools,pgf,pstricks}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[page number]

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{with \texttt{columns}}
\vspace{-7cm}

\begin{columns}[T]
  \column{.48\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{image.eps}

  \column{.48\textwidth}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item right part
    \item test2
    \item test3
  \end{itemize}  
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I don't know why this is the case. It probably has to do with all the warnings one gets during the `dvipdfmx` run. Hopefully someone can answer this part of the question.

Comment: Interesting finding. I tried to use `\vspace` and `\hspace` to adjust it, but it seems that `\hspace` is not working.....

Comment: I also found the same problem happening on `block` environment when converting to pdf......

Comment: @Yifen: Have you tried compiling using `xelatex`?