# Slide divided horizontally and vertically

Tags: beamer, minipage

I need to include a slide structured as in the picture below in a beamer presentation in latex. Could you help me to construct it?

Basically, the slide is divided horizontally into two parts. The first part is in turn divided vertically into 3 parts. There is a red circle including some listed items. There are arrows linking the 3 columns in the fits horizontal part.

I have found related questions, e.g., [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26836/how-to-split-a-frame-of-beamer-into-2-parts-minipage-side-by-side) but I have too many peculiar elements to include and it is hard for me to understand how to combine them.

[image]

Comment: You could use beamers `columns` environment. I'd suggest to use one for the top 3 columns and one for for the bottom 3 columns (leaving the last two empty)

Comment: @samcarter Thanks. I have also to add arrows and the red circle. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

The basic structure of your slide can be reproduced with beamer columns. To add a red circle on top of it, have a look at `tikz`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{columns}[onlytextwidth]
\begin{column}{.25\textwidth}
a

b
\end{column}
\begin{column}{.1\textwidth}
$\Leftarrow$
\end{column}
\begin{column}{.25\textwidth}
a

b
\end{column}
\begin{column}{.1\textwidth}
$\Leftarrow$
\end{column}
\begin{column}{.25\textwidth}
a

b
\end{column}
\end{columns}

\bigskip

\begin{columns}[onlytextwidth]
\begin{column}{.25\textwidth}
I

L
\end{column}
\begin{column}{.1\textwidth}
\end{column}
\begin{column}{.25\textwidth}
\end{column}
\begin{column}{.1\textwidth}
\end{column}
\begin{column}{.25\textwidth}
\end{column}
\end{columns}


\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\draw[red] (0.5,1) circle (1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}



\end{document}
```

[image]

Another version with `tikzmark`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,fit,shapes.geometric,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{A frame with 3 columns}
 \begin{columns}[onlytextwidth]
  \begin{column}{0.3\textwidth}
   ~
   \begin{itemize}
    \item \tikzmarknode{Lx1}{x1}
    \item x2
    \item x3    
   \end{itemize}
  \end{column}
  \vrule
  \begin{column}{0.3\textwidth}
   BLAH 2
   \begin{itemize}
    \item \tikzmarknode{Mx1}{x1}
    \item x2
    \item x3    
   \end{itemize}
  \end{column}
  \vrule
  \begin{column}{0.3\textwidth}
   BLAH 3
   \begin{itemize}
    \item \tikzmarknode{Rx1}{x1}
    \item x2
    \item x3    
   \end{itemize}
  \end{column}
 \end{columns}
 \hrule
 \begin{itemize}
  \item x1
  \item x2
  \item \tikzmarknode{Bx3}{x3}  
 \end{itemize}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\draw[line width=1mm,-latex] ([xshift=-5mm]Mx1.west) -- ++ (-1.2,0);
\draw[line width=1mm,-latex] ([xshift=-5mm]Rx1.west) -- ++ (-1.2,0);
\path let \p1=($(Lx1.center)-(Bx3.center)$),\n1={90+atan2(\y1,\x1)} in  
node[fit=(Lx1) (Bx3),draw=red,ellipse,inner ysep=-3mm,rotate fit=\n1]{};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks: can we add the vertical and horizontal lines separating the spaces as in my picture? Thanks